# ElasticSearch and SSD fatigue?

Tags: macos, docker, elasticsearch

I'm about to use ES docker image with MacOS (Rails app as back-end) and I'm wondering how bad it could be for my SSD given the fact how ofter ES writes/reads data.

Is it safe?

I don't know much about ES so can't really say how big / much data the ES will use while I work on the app but let's assume the worst.

Wouldn't it damage my SSD disk (rMBP 13" 2015 128 GB) within relatively short lifespan (let's say 1 year)?

Comment: There are two parts to this question, and I'm not convinced that *either* is on-topic here. (1) What's the write rate from a heavily-loaded (per question) ES instance? -- this is a question about system administration, not software development; (2) What's the hardware specification for a 2015 MBP's SSDs, in terms of lifetime writes permitted? -- this is a question about specs for a specific vendor's hardware.

Comment: ...that said, insofar as this is a dev instance, you aren't going to be running at max write load for months on end -- so my off-the-cuff answer is "don't worry about it". The "worst case" that matters for production hardware lifespan analysis is an entirely different beast than the worst case for a developer's laptop.